# Clicking on tab in blue prism in windows application

Tags: prism

I am trying to click on a tab in windows application using blue prism(automation).I am unable to do that. Please help

Answer (score 0):

What kind of tab?
I'm working on a robot that uses windows based application and I was able to make it work.

You need to be creative whit Application Modeller. Whit widows applications theres not much of a problems, almost anything can be done.

I have some major problems with mainframe apps, terminal sesions like - ICBS.

Comment: Yes, I got it, while identifying element(tab) I switched to accessibility mode.Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

When you spying an element try to do it using TAB index property and follow the pattern how it changing from element to element. May be it help you to develop some kind of logic.Just an Idea.